# Is there any way to pass only 1 time Buffer string and only 1 time Regex check

Tags: c#, system.reactive

My string representation of byte buffer `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b.Buffer)` is **"Foo:Foo1"**.

I would like to parse the string against Regex and then bind with 2 different property (`Message1` and `Message2`) of class `RemoteData`.

```
public class RemoteData
{
    private string _message1;
    private string _message2;

    public RemoteData(string Message1, string Message2)
    {
        this.Message1 = Message1;
        this.Message2 = Message2;
    }

    public string Message1
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsValidMessage(_message1))
                return _message1 = _message1.Split(':')[0].ToString();
            return _message1;
        }
        set
        {
            _message1 = value;
        }
    }

    public string Message2
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsValidMessage(_message2))
                return _message2 = _message2.Split(':')[1].ToString();
            return _message2;
        }
        set
        {
            _message2 = value;
        }
    }

    private static bool IsValidMessage(string value)
    {
        const string expression = (@"([\w]+):([\w]+)");

        return Regex.IsMatch(value, expression, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

I am returning `IObservable` of class `RemoteData` and below code is working good.

```
 public static IObservable<RemoteData> UdpStream(IPEndPoint endpoint)
    {
        return Observable.Using(() => new UdpClient(endpoint),
            udpClient => Observable.Defer(() =>
                udpClient.ReceiveAsync().ToObservable()).Repeat().Select(b => new RemoteData(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b.Buffer), Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b.Buffer))));
    }
```

Question: Is there any way that,

1. I can pass only one time `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b.Buffer)` in `Observable` **Select**?
2. I have to do only one time regex check and convert the string and assign to various properties of class `RemoteData`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a solution, I am using another class `SplitData` and checking Regex at `RemoteData` constructor.

```
public class SplitData
{
    public string Message1 { get; set; }
    public string Message2 { get; set; }
}
public class RemoteData
{
    private SplitData _SplitData;

    public RemoteData(string Message)
    {
        this.Message = Message;
        if (IsValidMessage(this.Message))
        {
            _SplitData = new SplitData
            {
                Message1 = Message.Split(':')[0].ToString(),
                Message2 = Message.Split(':')[1].ToString()
            };
        }
    }

    public string Message { get; }
    public SplitData SplitData
    {
        get
        {
            return _SplitData;
        }
        set
        {
            _SplitData = value;
        }
    }
    private static bool IsValidMessage(string value)
    {
        const string expression = (@"([\w]+):([\w]+)");

        return Regex.IsMatch(value, expression, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

and passing one parameter to `UdpStream` method,

```
public static IObservable<RemoteData> UdpStream(IPEndPoint endpoint)
    {
        return Observable.Using(() => new UdpClient(endpoint),
            udpClient => Observable.Defer(() =>
                udpClient.ReceiveAsync().ToObservable()).Repeat().Select(b => new RemoteData(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b.Buffer))));
    }
```

Please let me know if any other better way. Thanks!